# How can i add inline script in joomla 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla

I'm trying to add script in my teplate but it often gives an error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in
>   Z:\home\localhost\www\RealEstate\templates\real_estate\index.php on
>   line 21

This is my code:

```
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

$app             = JFactory::getApplication();
$doc             = JFactory::getDocument();
$user            = JFactory::getUser();
$this->language  = $doc->language;
$this->direction = $doc->direction;

$params = $app->getTemplate(true)->params;


$doc->addStyleSheet('templates/' . $this->template . '/css/swiper.min.css');
$doc->addStyleSheet('templates/' . $this->template . '/css/style.css');

JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
$doc->addScript('templates/' . $this->template . '/js/swiper.min.js');
$doc->addScriptDeclaration('
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
   nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
   prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
   pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
   slidesPerView: 3,
   slidesPerColumn: 2,
   paginationClickable: true,
   spaceBetween: -15,
   });
});
');

?>
```

I'm also trying this:

```
JHtml::_('jquery.framework', false);
$doc->addScript('templates/' . $this->template . '/js/swiper.min.js');
$doc->addScriptDeclaration('
  $(document).ready(function() {
   var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
   nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
   prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
   pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
   slidesPerView: 3,
   slidesPerColumn: 2,
   paginationClickable: true,
   spaceBetween: -15,
   });
});
');
```

Neither doesn't work but gives an error.
Would you please guys shed light on what i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are concatenating string in a wrong way

Put that script inside double-quotes

```
$doc->addScriptDeclaration("
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
   nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
   prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
   pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
   slidesPerView: 3,
   slidesPerColumn: 2,
   paginationClickable: true,
   spaceBetween: -15,
   });
});
");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Try:
$doc->addScriptDeclaration('
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   var swiper = new Swiper(\'.swiper-container\', {
   nextButton: \'.swiper-button-next\',
   prevButton: \'.swiper-button-prev\',
   pagination: \'.swiper-pagination\',
   slidesPerView: 3,
   slidesPerColumn: 2,
   paginationClickable: true,
   spaceBetween: -15,
   });
});
');
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to delimit strings without a need to escape quotes is **Heredoc** syntax.

```
$doc->addScriptDeclaration(<<<JS_SCRIPT
  $(document).ready(function() {
   var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
       nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
       prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
       pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
       slidesPerView: 3,
       slidesPerColumn: 2,
       paginationClickable: true,
       spaceBetween: -15,
   });
  });
JS_SCRIPT
);
```

> **Heredoc** text behaves just like a double-quoted string, without the
>   double quotes. This means that quotes in a heredoc do not need to be
>   escaped, but the escape codes [listed above](https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) can still be used.
>   Variables are expanded, but the same care must be taken when
>   expressing complex variables inside a heredoc as with strings.
>   The closing identifier must begin in the first column of the line.
>   Also, the identifier must follow the same naming rules as any other
>   label in PHP: it must contain only alphanumeric characters and
>   underscores, and must start with a non-digit character or underscore.
>
> **Warning** It is very important to note that the line with the closing identifier
>   must contain no other characters, except a semicolon (;). That means
>   especially that the identifier may not be indented, and there may not
>   be any spaces or tabs before or after the semicolon. It's also
>   important to realize that the first character before the closing
>   identifier must be a newline as defined by the local operating system.
>   This is \n on UNIX systems, including Mac OS X. The closing delimiter
>   must also be followed by a newline.
>
> If this rule is broken and the closing identifier is not "clean", it
>   will not be considered a closing identifier, and PHP will continue
>   looking for one. If a proper closing identifier is not found before
>   the end of the current file, a parse error will result at the last
>   line.
>
> Heredocs can not be used for initializing class properties. Since PHP
>   5.3, this limitation is valid only for heredocs containing variables.

Reference: [Heredoc](https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)